# How to show a spinner in Meteor for the duration of an event

Tags: events, meteor

In a Meteor app, one function that runs on a click takes a while to run on some slower devices. As a result, on these slow devices, the app doesn't seem to do anything until after the function has completed.

The function in question loops through a largish array. It does not do any external stuff, or method calls.

To visually clue in the user, I want to show a spinner to the user (on slow devices). Ideally, I would show the spinner at the start of the event, and then remove the spinner at the end of the event. However, if my understanding of Meteor is correct (and based on what seems to be happening when I try it out), all template updates specified during the event are only propagated at the end of the event. So, as a result, the spinner never shows.

How can I make this work as intended?

Current setup (edit with actual code):

In categories.html:

```
                    {{#if hasSubCategories}}
                        <a href='#_' id='categorySelect-{{id}}' class='btn categorySelect pull-right
                            {{#if allSubsSelected}}
                                btn-danger
                            {{else}}
                                btn-success 
                            {{/if}}
                        '>{{#if isFlipping}}<span id='spinner-{{id}}'>flip</span>{{/if}}<span class="glyphicon 
                            {{#if allSubsSelected}}
                                glyphicon-remove
                            {{else}}
                                glyphicon-ok
                            {{/if}}
                        " aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                    {{/if}}
```

In categories.js:

```
Template.categories.events({
    "click .categorySelect": function (event) {
        Session.set('categorySpinner', this.id);

        categoryFlipper(this.id, function() {
            Session.set('categorySpinner', "");
        });

        return false;
    },
});

Template.categories.helpers({
    allSubsSelected: function() {
        var finder = Categories.find({parentId: this.id});

        var allSelected = true;
        finder.forEach(function(item) {
            if (!($.inArray(item.id, Session.get("categoriesSelected")) !== -1)) {
                allSelected = false;
            }
        });

        return allSelected;
    },
isFlipping: function() {
    if (Session.get("categorySpinner") == this.id)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

});
```

In main.js:

```
categoryFlipper = function (id, callback) {
    var finder = Categories.find({parentId: id});

    var allSelected = true;
    finder.forEach(function(item) {
        if (!($.inArray(item.id, Session.get("categoriesSelected")) !== -1)) {
            allSelected = false;
        }
    });

    var t = Session.get("categoriesSelected");

    if (allSelected) {
        finder.forEach(function(item) {
            t.splice($.inArray(item.id, t), 1);
        });
    }
    else {
        finder.forEach(function(item) {
            if (!($.inArray(item.id, t) !== -1)) {
                t.push(item.id);
            }
        });         
    }

    Session.set("categoriesSelected", t);

    callback();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your sample code (though I still don't have a complete picture since I don't see the helper definitions for `allSubsSelected` and `isFlipping`), I'm pretty sure that your `categoryFlipper` function executes so quickly that you never really see the spinner. There's nothing in that code that would really take any significant amount of time. You have a `find()` call, but that's not what really takes the most amount of time. It's your `subscribe()` call that you usually need to figure in some delay for as the data is pulled from the database to the mini-mongo client in the browser.

Something like this is fairly common:

```
{{#unless Template.subscriptionsReady}}
  spinner here...
{{else}}
  Content here.
{{/unless}}
```

That way, while your subscription is triggering the publication and pulling data down, `Template.subscriptionsReady` returns false, and the spinner is shown. Try that approach instead.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but the spinner would refuse to show, which suggested to me that, as in your example, the "#theButton click" event would be fully processed before any changes in that event would be propagated to the app. And, isn't that also how Meteor advertises to work?

Comment: Also, doesn't a Meteor.call call a method defined on the server? I need to call a function defined on the client.

Comment: @MastaBaba I just used a method call as an example. You didn't post enough of your code so I don't know what function is being run in the background or why it's not working with the spinner.

Comment: Share some actual code (if you can) instead of pseudo-code. Chances are, `doSomeLongCalculation()` is asynchronous which is why you're not seeing your spinner.

Comment: @MastaBaba Cool, I'll get back to you tonight or tomorrow some time.

Comment: I'm still having a noticeable lag between button press and button update, without the spinner being shown. I added some more code as per your request.

Comment: I'm kinda stumped to be honest. I don't see anything that's wrong, though it's strange that `forEach` (which operates on arrays) works on your `finder` variable which is a cursor, _not_ an array. `var finder = Categories.find({parentId: id}).fetch` might be a better way to go.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Doesn't this say otherwise: https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/cursor.forEach/

Comment: That's straight up Mongo though. I'm talking about the `find` method in Meteor which is different.

Comment: Oh dear. I thought I was starting to understand the Mongo/Meteor setup :/